# c# How to format string for use in HTML attribute?

Tags: c#, html, string-formatting

I was wondering if there are any c# libraries that will readily format a string to be used in a onclick html attribute property.

I am using c# to dynamically generate an html page and am dynamically generating the javascript for some onclick events. I want to make sure characters such as &"\ ... etc does not cause the html to break or be ignored. For example in the following example of I wanted to display the alert message h\&#3m, I wouldn't be able to do so unless I created separate logic to handle the \ and &:

```js
function method1(inputValue){
  alert(inputValue);
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="method1('h\&#3m')"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to check out the HtmlEncode method of HttpServerUtility.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx